# how to check if a service implements an interface in grails

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.3

I have an interface "**TestInterface**" and grails service "**TestService**" that implements the "TestInterface". But when I test if I have a service  that implements the interface like this:

```
application.serviceClasses?.each { serviceClazz ->

            if(serviceClazz instanceof TestInterface) {
                println "service name => "+ serviceClazz.name;
            }
}
```

The result is I am not getting anything neither error nor my expectation ( *service name => TestService* )

I have also tried changing the serviceClazz to serviceClazz.class,serviceClazz.metaClass in the if condition but still not working.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
if (TestInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(serviceClazz)) {
    ... 
}
```

---

#### UPDATE

So I managed to run the actual example using **Grails 2.3.11**.

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        grailsApplication.serviceClasses.each { serviceClazz ->
            if (TestInterface.isAssignableFrom(serviceClazz.clazz)) {
                println serviceClazz
            }
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

As you can see, the important part is **clazz** in `serviceClazz.clazz`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That throws an exception , so I changed it to isAssignableFrom(serviceClazz.class) but still it returns false.

Comment: What's the exception? I'm away from computer now. Let me test in a few hours and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.apposit.mmp.grails.client.event.TestInterface.isAssignableFrom() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass) values: [Artefact > Topic]
|

Comment: But you can mark it as correct answer, right? I'd appreciate it :)